# Using connection string from appsettings.json to startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, appsettings

Currently in Startup, I have my sql server string looking like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var connection = @"Server=servername;Database=database;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
    services.AddDbContext<CRAMSContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
}
```

How do I use what's in my appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
    "ConnectionString": "Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=database;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

To look something like this in the new ASP.NET 1.0 CORE new setup to look paramertized like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var connection2 = new SqlConnection connectionString;
    services.AddDbContext<CRAMSContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection2));
}
```

Also, if I have a different database for the test and qa, how do I let the ASP.NET app know to use a connection for each environment?

My startup class is already defined at the root like this:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use proper structure for connection strings:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "xxx"
  }
}
```

Access in startup.cs:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Comment: I get: `Error: The name "Configuration" does not exist in the current context`. Which package am i missing? EDIT: Never mind, this is an issue in the pre-release of v2. In 1.1 stable version it's ok.

Comment: you are missing the `IConfiguartionRoot` method in the Startup.cs file. Name it configuaration, add a get to it, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

First add package for SQL server "**Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer**" then add

services.AddDbContext(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));